# Function That Weights Toward End of Range [0,1]

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I apologize in advance if the question I am asking is elementary.  Admittedly, I am not all that literate when it comes to mathematics so I have been struggling to search the correct terms and find what I need.  That being the case, I may be duplicating another question already on this site, for which I apologize.

I am trying to find a function that, given a sequence of numbers from [0,1] (inclusive), would push the output closer to one end of the range or the other, biasing away from the center.  For example, if the value being passed into the function was 0.4, the output would be closer to 0 than 0.5 (the middle).

I've have a good start with the function:

$
y=\frac{(x-0.5)^{1/3}}{1.59}+0.5
$

[Image of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbomu.png)

However, the function is almost *too* biased toward the ends and I am failing to gentle it.  Additionally, passing either 0 or 1 through does not return the same as the result (which I would like).

I imagine if the center part of the function (the straight vertical line) was a bit shorter that would do the trick.  However, I've been unable to shorten it while still having the function pass through (or near) (0,0) and (1,1).  For example, if I multiply x by, say, 0.5 the center line does diminish in length but the function passes near (0,0) and (2,1), as shown below.

[Image of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUl1L.png)

If someone might be able to instruct me as to how to modify the function to accomplish that, I would be very grateful.  I'm certainly also open to other approaches or types of functions that might accomplish the same ends.

Thanks very much.

Comment: [Gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) is a standard way to do this.

Comment: You could base it on a suitable window of a logistic function (or another sigmoid function), and then shift and scale it so it passes through (0,0), (.5,.5) and (1,1).

Comment: @Karl: I appreciate that suggestion.  I implemented a gamma correction function as well but it wasn't doing exactly what I wanted.  I ended up finding a contrast correction function to behave more closely to my expectations: $f(x) = a((x - 128) + 128)$, where $a$ is the "correction" factor, with larger values increasing contrast and smaller values decreasing.  Output needs to be clamped to [0,255].

Comment: @Mitten: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider functions of the form $f(x) = a(x - 0.5)^b + 0.5$, with the constraints that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.  Then:

$$f(0) = a(-0.5)^b + 0.5 = 0 \implies a(-0.5)^b = -0.5$$
$$f(1) = a(0.5)^b + 0.5 = 1 \implies a(0.5)^b = 0.5$$

Require $b$ to be a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ with odd numerator and denominator.  This allows allows us to define $(\sqrt[q]{-0.5})^p$ as a negative real number.

Solving $a(0.5)^b = 0.5$ for $a$ gives us $a = 2^{b-1}$.  For example, with $b = 1/3$, we get $a \approx 0.629960525$ (and $\frac{1}{a} \approx 1.58740105$, which is how you got the 1.59 in your function).

We can measure “bias” using [the standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the function applied to uniformly-distributed values in $[0, 1]$.

- $f(x) = 0.5$ has a SD of 0.
- $f(x) = x$ has a SD of 0.288675.
- $f(x) = 2^{1/3-1}(x - 0.5)^{1/3}$ has a SD of 0.387298.
- $f(x) = \operatorname{round}(x)$ has a SD of 0.5.

So, you want a $b$ such that $f(x) = 2^{b-1}(x - 0.5)^b + 0.5$ has a bigger SD that $b = 1$, but a smaller one than $b = \frac{1}{3}$.  Try one of these:

- $b = \frac{3}{7} \implies SD = 0.366900$
- $b = \frac{5}{9} \implies SD = 0.344124$
- $b = \frac{3}{5} \implies SD = 0.337100$
- $b = \frac{5}{7} \implies SD = 0.320844$
- $b = \frac{7}{9} \implies SD = 0.312772$

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to respond and dig into my question.  Am I right that the formula in question then is $f(x) = 2^{(b-1)}(x - 0.5)^b$?

Comment: Following up briefly on my earlier comment.  Read through your response again and that is the formula.  However, I did notice that it seems to be behaving a little bit differently than my original.

For example, if x is 0.8 and b is 0.33, your formula yields ~0.422.  $f(0.8) = 2^{0.33 - 1}(0.8 - 0.5)^{0.33} = 2^{-0.66}(0.3)^{0.33} = ~0.422$.


In my original formula, it comes out to ~0.922.  $f(0.8) = {{(0.8 - 0.5)^ {0.33}} / 1.59} + 0.5$.  It seems like the difference may be because of last addition of 0.5?

Comment: @Antillies: Yes, I forgot to include it the last time I wrote the formula.  It doesn't affect the SD calculation, though.

Comment: Not a problem!  With that addition, your formula matches up.  I've gone ahead and accepted your answer.  Thank you again for your time.